# Display category image as banner on single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to display the category image as banner in the woocommerce single product page. I'm using this code, but it shows all the category image.

```
if(is_single()) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
      $category_name = $term->name;
      $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
     echo '<img class="absolute '.$category_name.' category-image" src="'.$image.'">';
    }
    }
```

I want only to show the category image. when I click on the product, it shows its category image as banner.

Answer (score 1):

**Problem in code** : What you have done in your coding is, you are **fetching all the terms**([get_the_terms](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms#Description)) **assinged to the product**.That is why it is displaying all the images.

**Solution** : Either you can `change your code` to get banner image of particular product or else you can simply put `dummy condition` to get only one image.

Code for dummy condition :

```
if(is_single()) {
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    $i=0; //Variable for dummy condition
    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
        if($i==0): //Dummy Condition
            $category_name = $term->name;
            $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
            echo '<img class="absolute '.$category_name.' category-image" src="'.$image.'">';
            $i++; //Increment it to make condition false
        endif;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: thank you for the reply but as your answer you added the condtion this will not match the category. i want when product is clicked then show the category image for that ..as i have no sub category in woocommrece

Comment: Have you tried my code ? Condition is not for matching the category ... As you mentioned in your question, you are getting all the category images... And you have used get_the_terms function..And if you look at [documentation' description](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms#Description) you will get more idea.

Answer (score 0):

You slect child category that why display all category image